# "Form is not defined" error using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am learning jquery and am writing some very simple jquery code that posts some variables to a method in my controller. I get “myform is not defined” error in firebug when using the code posted below.

Here is my html:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get(){
            $.post('jqtest/test',{name: myform.myname.value},
            function (output){
                $('#username').html(output).show();          
            }    
        );
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <form name="myform">
        <input type="text" name="myname">
        <input type="button" value="Get" onclick="get();">
    </form>
    <div id="username"></div>
</body>
```

Here is my codeigniter controller code:

```
class Jqtest extends CI_Controller {

function _Jqtest() {
    parent::controller();
}

function index() {
    $this->load->view("jqtest/jqtest.html");
}

function test() {
    print_r($_POST);
    $this->load->view("jqtest/jqtest.html");
}

}
```

When the Get button is clicked, the test method should print the POST values.
When I run the code in FireFox, it's not working (nothing is getting printed out). When I checked the firebug console, I found a "myform is not defined" error.

I know there is something wrong with my jQuery get() function, can anybody please help me out, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

"myform is not defined" error occures because you have not set myform  in javascript.

try Jquery's serializeArray()

```
var myform= $('form').serializeArray();

function get(){
            $.post('jqtest/test',{name: myform.myname.value},
            function (output){
                $('#username').html(output).show();          
                }   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function get(){
        $.post('jqtest/test',{name: $('form[name="myform"] input[name="myname"]').val()},
        function (output){
            $('#username').html(output).show();          
        }    
    );
    }
```

Comment: Good luck on your jquery learning.  I suggest also looking into jQuery's event binding : http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
myform.myname.value
```

with

```
$('input[name="myname"]').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this :

```
document.myform.myname.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Form should have an id    `<form name="myform" id="myformid">`

```
$.post('jqtest/test',{name: myform.myname.value},
```

would replaced with the below code :)

```
$.post('jqtest/test',{name: $( 'input[name="myname"]' ).val()},
```

If u need to send the all form value then u should use serialize. it's faster.

### [API DOC: serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

If u use same same input name for different form. then u should have to write as below:

```
var $form = $( "#myformid" );
name = $form.find( 'input[name="myname"]' ).val();
```

and post will be:

```
$.post('jqtest/test',{name: name},
```